# NodeInvocationException when trying to get data from localStorage in stateless React component

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, react-router, typescript-typings, server-side-rendering

I have implemented my app layout like this:

```
const Layout: React.SFC<IDefaultProps> = props => {
  const { component: Component, ...rest } = props;
  const logged = userServices.getUserLocalStorage();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={matchProps =>
        logged != null ? (
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <NavMenuLogged {...matchProps} />                
            <div className="row wu-content">
              <Component {...matchProps} />
            </div>                
            <Footer />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

hoping to save user's login info inside localStorage, and from there, be able to redirect the user to login; but I've findout that I can't access localStorage inside a SFC component. Does anyone has a solution for this? (elegant, or not...)

This is the getUserLocalStorage() function:

```
export function getUserLocalStorage(){
    let user:Utils.User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user") || '{}');
    return user;
}
```

This is the error i got:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NodeInvocationException: localStorage is not defined
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
at Object.getUserLocalStorage [as b] (E:\Trabajo\...\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:9138:27)
at Layout (E:\...\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:38836:102)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (E:\...\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:43899:14)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (E:\...\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:43875:19)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (E:\...\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:43778:21)
at Object.mountComponent (E:\...\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:11753:35)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (E:\...\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:43961:34)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (E:\Trabajo\...\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:43848:21)
at Object.mountComponent (E:\...\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:11753:35)
at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (E:\...\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:47391:44)
```

Comment: can you post `userServices.getUserLocalStorage();`

Comment: I've edited the question to include the function

Comment: Can you maybe post the error message as well?

Comment: I have added the error i get

Comment: Feels like the error happens on the server, not in the browser. It makes sense: there's no `localStorage` in the Node environment. Please confirm that you see the error in the server console and not in the browser.

Comment: yes, I can confirm the error is on the server, not the browser console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the error appears on the server, during the server-side render phase, it is very likely to be caused by absence of `localStorage` in Node environment. There's simply no such thing in Node, it's browser-specific API. So the function throws a [ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) in disguise (perhaps because it's ASP.NET, but I'm not sure).

I assume there is no way to retrieve user information at server-side render step anyway, and user data for this particular case is only stored in user's browser, in local storage. In this case, it probably makes sense to check if `localStorage` even exists and, if not, *fall back to a default value:*

```
export function getUserLocalStorage(){
    if (typeof localStorage === 'undefined') {
        // will safely return if localStorage is not defined
        return {};
    }

    let user:Utils.User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user") || '{}');

    return user;
}
```

The `typeof •` works with any `•`, even variables or references that were not previously defined. It's the safest operation to check if a certain reference exists in scope.

Compare to

```
if (localStorage) {
    // will throw ReferenceError is localStorage is not defined
}
```

Because you may not want to do client/server code splitting at this point in time, the `typeof`-powered check might be the best option. This way, you ensure that following code will only run in an environment where `localStorage` reference is available (in most cases, in browser's global scope). The same practice you might be already applying to check if `window` is defined.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is related to how you set up the app, when you call `localStorage`, it has to happen on the client side, not on the server side. As node, does not have a local storage.

I would try this:
Change it to a class component instead of using a functional component, then do

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log(localStorage) // or whatever you need to do here.
}
```

If you do not want to remove your SFC, you can create your own HOC, or use library like `recompose`. Here is a code snippet for using recompose:

```
const SFCWithLifeCycleHook = lifecycle({
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(localStorage) //do something here...
  }
})(SFC);
```

Comment: How is the OP supposed to call `componentDidMount` on an SFC?

Comment: you can change to a class component, does it have to be a functional comp?

Comment: What if there are more than one such components in the codebase? Remaking SFC into class components would require rewriting all of them.

Comment: you can make HOC instead then. Keep the function as it. Create your own HOC, or use library like recompose. I will update the post with a bit more detail.

Comment: @Leogoesger, no, it odes not have to be a SFC, as a matter of fact I was thinking on change it to a class component. Could this change affect the performance?

Comment: @OscarCabreraRodríguez. "Stateless (functional) components are no faster than the stateful (class)". https://moduscreate.com/blog/react_component_rendering_performance/.